# My bashrc stopped working when I moved it to a new enviornment?

Tags: windows, git, macos, bash, shell

I just moved all my files from Windows to OS X ( on the Macbook Air now ).  I used the bash shell on windows and I thought that I would be using the same bash shell ( or similar ) on my mac.  The one on windows came with my installation of git.  OS X has one built in already, called terminal.

`.bash_profile` has a single line `source /root/config/bashrc.sh`

and `bashrc.sh` looks like this:

```
warp() {
  cd /c/root/ ; 
}

launch() { 
  git add -A . ;
  git commit -m $1 ;
  git push heroku master ;
  echo $1 ;
}

#defaults
export VISUAL=sublime_text
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"

#aliases
alias i="ipconfig"
alias s="sublime_text &"
alias l="ls -a -l"

#commands
warp
#grunt watch &
#sublime_text &
clear

#output
echo ""
echo "************************************************"
echo " - .bashrc loaded and sourced to bashrc.sh"
echo " -  added functions warp() and launch()"
echo " -  added alias (i)pconfig (s)ublime (l)s -a -l"
echo "************************************************"
echo ""
```

and here is it "blowing up" when I run it. The terminal gave the errors below.  Previously it had no errors.

```
'bash: /root/config/bashrc.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'bash: /root/config/bashrc.sh: line 1: `warp() {
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84693/discussion-on-question-by-cade-galt-my-bashrc-file-blew-up-when-i-moved-it-to-a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Issue is permission related with the indirect sourcing of .bashrc config from `/root/config/bashrc.sh`
>
> The normal solution would just be to directly write your config to ~/.bashrc file

**~/.bashrc**

```
warp() {
  cd /c/root/ ; 
}

launch() { 
  git add -A . ;
  git commit -m $1 ;
  git push heroku master ;
  echo $1 ;
}

#defaults
export VISUAL=sublime_text
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"

#aliases
alias i="ipconfig"
alias s="sublime_text &"
alias l="ls -a -l"

#commands
warp
#grunt watch &
#sublime_text &
clear

#output
echo ""
echo "************************************************"
echo " - .bashrc loaded and sourced to bashrc.sh"
echo " -  added functions warp() and launch()"
echo " -  added alias (i)pconfig (s)ublime (l)s -a -l"
echo "************************************************"
echo ""
```

**alternative solution [ not recommended ]**

If you use following in your ~/.bashrc

```
source /root/config/bashrc.sh;
```

then you must give the user read and execute permission on the following files

```
/root
/root/config
/root/config/bashrc.sh
```

its not usually a great idea to give +rx on /root.

Or you could put the config somewhere like /etc/user.bashrc.sh where you already have access as a user to /etc..

Comment: Do I have to change permissions in 3 different places if I want to keep my file where it is?

Comment: yes - it needs +rx on both directories and the file itself.. test it out

Comment: I tried using a hard link using `ln` but this had the same problem as using `source` in the file itself.  I guess changing the file permissions in 3 places is necessary.  I would have thought the OS would have been smart enough to know that if I give full rwx access to a file it could give it to just that file and not need the directories as well.

Comment: check this [unix directory permissions summary](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory#answer-13891)

Comment: I decided to just move my entire directory tree into my user folder to avoid all the chmod which doesn't seem safe.  There was another problem, in that b.c. I downloaded this file ( it was mine ) from the internet, it still would not run it.  I had to copy paste the file to a new file so the system would accept it.  Finally I got it to work.  Sheeeeeeeeshhhhh!!!!!!!!!